# Is it possible to change the background of a keyboard or change the color of a key?

Tags: keyboard

I want to change the look and feel of the keyboard , by changing its background and also the color of individual keys. Please help if there is a way to do it.

Comment: You can theme keyboards, but it requires hacking the APK.

Comment: If u got the answer of this question then please post here, I want the answer of the same question...!!!

Comment: Yes you can change the look and feel of the keyboard. But for individual keys its not possible. you can set key background and show popup (this can be changed for different keys through coding). In the android sdk example you will find a keyboard example, you can make changes in xml placed in the layout folder and see the changes

Comment: I already use android sdk keyboard. But I want to be change the background color of each key. Is it possible? If yes then how, I dont want to be use of android:keyIcon...!!!

Comment: i did a detailed research on this , but finally i did not got any solution for that. but you can change the pop up of each key which comes on key press

Comment: How? Can you give me an example...?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not too attached to your current keyboard, there are loads of other ones you could try.

- [SlideIt](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dasur.slideit.vt.lite&feature=search_result) keyboard is good, and it has a new support for skins! so you can make it look however you want :)
- [Swype](http://swypeinc.com/) has about the same functionality as the former, with a single skin that is more of a darker grey.
- [FlexT9](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nuance.flext9.input&feature=search_result) has the same support as the first two, with a white skin.
- [SwiftKey](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&feature=search_result) is good if you don't like the swipe to type thing, and has a couple good-looking included skins.

The only way to change the default keyboard on your device though, will be rooting and finding a ROM that has a keyboard that you like (or making your own if you're developer inclined ;) )